# Set user defined sample rate for an ADC while Interfacing with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi

I have a current sensor connected to an ADC whose maximum sampling rate is 3300sps.

I need to save time domain data at fixed number of samples per second..

I am using Python to write the codes.

What would be the best way to ensure I get this maximum sampling rate of 3300sps?

So if someone could please explain this how I would go about, I would be very appreciative.

Thank you!

Comment: Use C not Python.

Comment: Could you plz let me know the issues faced in Python

Comment: Probably too slow for what you want to do.

Comment: How will C benefit us over Python, could u plz give your suggestions on this?

Comment: Python is an interpreted language, very slow for what you plan to do. C at least 10 x faster. Now, you can give a shot at both and compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the datasheet of the ADS1015, the config register (pg 16) can be set the data rate (bits 7:5) at a fixed value. You can use a python library like SMBus to set the register on the i2c bus:

```
import smbus
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
bus.write_byte_data(0x38,__,__)
```

A full sampling rate of 3300 is not possible on a linux based system like the Raspberry pi, you would probably need a RTOS based system running bare-metal c/c++. An arduino would probably be a little faster (you could get around 490S/s), if you add memory with high enough write speeds and large enough capacity.

Comment: Thanks Aditya for your valuable feedback. Irrespective of the type of ADC that I interface with RPi, what could be the maximum sampling frequency that our RPi can permit? Also, can u plz suggest some links/documentation related to basics of RTOS to be used in RPi since I am new to this field.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions. In the last line of "bus.write_byte_data(0x38,__,__)" could you plz let me know what does the underscore define?

Comment: So a Raspberry Pi uses a linux kernel, which is different from a RTOS kernel. This cannot be changed as the kernel is the basis upon which the OS works. Selecting a different microcontroller which has an RTOS kernel is your best bet here. Examples include a STM32 based microcontroller. However these are typically not recommended for beginners as they have a learning curve.
I have managed to get around a maximum of 200 S/s with the Raspberry pi using a carefully multithreaded code. An arduino could give you around 500 S/s but you need a SD Card adapter to store that much data.

Comment: If your application just needs the rate to be constant, you can look at resampling the input data using numpy. (look at the resample and bfill functions). 
Also most applications do not need a sampling rate of 3300S/s. Typically the sampling rate should be double the highest frequency you want to measure. If you are say building a HR Monitor, the highest frequency (HR) would be around 200 and a rate of 400 S/s would be enough to measure that. (Check Nyquist theorem)
The problem with a huge sampling rate when your application does not need it would introduce unnecessary HF Noise.

Comment: Look at the documentation of the function on github, the syntax is:
"bus.write_byte_data(0x38,<reg addr>,<value to write>) ..(I'm assuming 0x38 is the i2c address of the ADC)

Comment: Thanks Aditya for your valuable feedback. Through your posts many of my doubts have got cleared. Regarding resample and bfill command, I followed this link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.bfill.html .However, with resample/bfill command, it will create alteration of my data set which I cannot allow. Fo my application Nyquist sampling frequency varies from 1kHz to 10kHz.

Comment: Then look at specialized DAQ systems, the raspberry pi cannot provide such high sample rates. Audio range acquisition sets are relatively inexpensive, and provide data upto 30kHz.

Comment: Also mark this answer as the accepted one if the issue is settled on ADS1015.